# How to detect an image virus?

Tags: malware, detection

How can someone detect a malicious code, executable or not, inside an image file ?
What techniques and what programs are out there that will help you for the detection procedure ?

This question is a sequel to the question: [Can you get infected by viewing an image?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85546/can-you-get-infected-by-viewing-an-image)

Answer (score 2):

The nature of an exploit using an image often is a **buffer overrun**, for instance:

[Buffer Overrun in JPEG Processing (GDI+) Could Allow Code Execution (833987)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms04-028.aspx)

To defend against such an attack, all practices and techniques to detect attacks on the stack and heap of your image processing programs will help. Rigorously checking the source code is the first step. Other means include hardening OS and even using special hardware is an option.

A nice overview can be found in this [paper on buffer overruns.](http://www.cslab.pepperdine.edu/warford/cosc320/CACM-Buffer-Overflow.pdf)