# Arbitrary file upload, serve JPG as PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, wordpress

I'm trying out random older WordPress exploits on my local server, I'm currently in the process trying to get this one to work:

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/20083/

It doesn't read any headers, just seems to filter file extensions.
I am able to upload **{Filename}.php.jpg** files as mentioned in the specified URL above. But what caught my curiosity was;

```
Plugin does not properly filter filetypes, which allows for the upload of filetypes in the following format: 
filename.php.jpg
Vulnerable hosts will serve such files as a php file, allowing for malicious files to be uploaded and executed.
```

Opening the JPG just makes my browser throw an error, not seeing it as a valid image.

Which leads me to my question

Why would a server ever serve a JPG as PHP? (without editing .htaccess or php require())?

Comment: Have a look at [Files with Multiple Extensions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is not directly linked to this exploit, but by a weak web server configuration.

For instance:

- Apache offers through *mod_mime* the possibility to [serve files with multiple extension](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext). This extension is designed to serve the same way files such as `welcome.html.fr` or `welcome.fr.html` (ie. french version of the `welcome.html` file). However it can be tricked to interpret `myuploadedfile.php.jpg` as a PHP script...
- Nginx offers a virtual directory system allowing to have virtual sub-directories below a dynamic script. For instance, a URL like `/agenda.php/2015/june/6` will execute the file `agenda.php` (SCRIPT_FILENAME) with `/2015/june/6` as parameter (PATH_INFO). However you may trick him to execute your uploaded file (which does not even need to have include the `.php` extension) by using a URL such as `/myuploadedfile.jpg/anything.php`: it will be accepted as a PHP script due to the `.php` extension, then the URL will be divided into SCRIPT_FILENAME and PATH_INFO as described above, and finally the order will be given to the PHP interpretor to execute `myuploadedfile.jpg` content.

Comment: This cleared a lot up, you have my gratitude. Am I correct to assume that I would not be able to abuse these particular exploits on my server unless I configure my environment to do so? Eg. mod_mime (Assume my environment has default configurations with nothing but the latest WordPress and the upload plugin.)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Hopefully servers are usually installed with safe defaults :), most of such issue comes from old, historical configuration...

Comment: In case anyone is interested, there's a follow up question to this answer there: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/218081/how-can-nginx-run-a-file-with-jpg-extension-as-php-file